# Bouncy Castle AuthorityInfoAccess Extension

Tags: certificate, bouncycastle, x509, attributecertificate

I'm trying to develop a X.509 Attribute Certificate generator with Bouncy Castle and I need to add an `AuthorityInfoAccess` extension. However, I can't find a non-deprecated way to do that!

The most-recent Bouncy Castle API Documentation doesn't show any clear way to build this extension and there is no example on their repository about that.

The answers I found about it refer to a `X509Extensions.AuthorityInfoAccess`, but it's deprecated!

Is there any trick about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OIDs in `X509Extensions` were deprecated in favor of `X509Extension` but that was also deprecated in favor of [`org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension.authorityInfoAccess`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/Extension.html#authorityInfoAccess)

You don't say if you already have the content; if not, that uses [`org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AuthorityInformationAccess`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/AuthorityInformationAccess.html) (note Information not just Info) which in turn uses similar `AccessDescription` and `GeneralName`

Comment: Yep, I had the content, but not the correct identifier. I'm using the `addExtension` method.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when deprecating a method/class/... the author indicates the new code to be used.

In this case, the message for X509Extensions.AuthorityInfoAccess says:

> ASN1ObjectIdentifier
>   org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extensions.AuthorityInfoAccess
>   Deprecated. **use X509Extension** value.
>   Authority Info Access

So, the message gives the hint that you should use X509Extension instead, as Dave Thomson already mentioned in his answer (well, he also mentioned a second deprecration also for X509Extension, but this is another story)

Comment: X509Extension is now deprecated as well, user  org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension instead.